# Parsing the USPTO bulk XML files using Python

Tags: python, xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import re
import codecs
import io


xml = open('ipa110106.xml')
line_num=0
f = open('workfile.xml', 'w')

for  line in xml:
   line_num+=1
   if line_num == 1:
       print (line)

   if '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' in line and line_num !=1:
       count =count+1
       line = line.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '')
   if '<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>' in line:
       line = line.replace('<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>', '')  
       count2+=1
   if "!DOCTYPE" in line:
    line=line.replace('<!DOCTYPE sequence-cwu SYSTEM "us-sequence-listing.dtd" [ ]>','')  
   f.write(line)  
f.close()

with open("workfile.xml") as f:
 xml = f.read()
 tree = ET.fromstring(re.sub(r"(<\?xml[^>]+\?>)", r"\1<root>", xml) + "</root>")
 root= tree.getroot()
```

Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

0
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-164-4d6fc9ea9aac>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Harshit/Downloads/ipa110106 (1)/parsing_test5.py', wdir='C:/Users/Harshit/Downloads/ipa110106 (1)')

  File "C:\Users\Harshit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Harshit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Harshit/Downloads/ipa110106 (1)/parsing_test5.py", line 41, in <module>
    root= tree.getroot()

AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'
```

I am trying to parse USPTO XML files to extract relevant information. These files are concatenation of multiple XML files and following the standard recommendations, given in this forum,I removed multiple instances of: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and `<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>` 
 as they were also causing an error:

> ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 2.

Finally, after removing these troublesome elements from the XML, I created a synthetic parent root to convert this file to a proper XML format. However, I was getting an error when I tried to parse this file and access its roots. I have attached the code in the post.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import re
import codecs
import io


xml = open('ipa110106.xml')
line_num=0
f = open('workfile.xml', 'w')

for  line in xml:
   line_num+=1
   if line_num == 1:
       print (line)

   if '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' in line and line_num !=1:
       count =count+1
       line = line.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '')
   if '<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>' in line:
       line = line.replace('<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>', '')  
       count2+=1
   if "!DOCTYPE" in line:
    line=line.replace('<!DOCTYPE sequence-cwu SYSTEM "us-sequence-listing.dtd" [ ]>','')  
   f.write(line)  
f.close()

with open("workfile.xml") as f:
 xml = f.read()
 tree = ET.fromstring(re.sub(r"(<\?xml[^>]+\?>)", r"\1<root>", xml) + "</root>")
 root= tree.getroot()
```

Also, the XML file is large and I can only share the link to it-[enter link description here](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data2/patent/application/redbook/fulltext/2011/)

A small sample of the XML (like) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-application lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23" file="US20110000001A1-20110106.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-application" country="US" date-produced="20101222" date-publ="20110106">
<us-bibliographic-data-application lang="EN" country="US">
<publication-reference>
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>20110000001</doc-number>
<kind>A1</kind>
<date>20110106</date>
</document-id>
</publication-reference>
<application-reference appl-type="utility">
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>12838840</doc-number>
<date>20100719</date>
</document-id>
</application-reference>
<us-application-series-code>12</us-application-series-code>
<priority-claims>
<priority-claim sequence="01" kind="national">
<country>IL</country>
<doc-number>189088</doc-number>
<date>20080128</date>
</priority-claim>
</priority-claims>
<classifications-ipcr>
<classification-ipcr>
```

Comment: where is the code? and sample of the xml

Comment: Do not post code in external links; include it in your post.

Comment: Hi, I have posted the code and link to XML. Sorry for an incomplete post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current PTO XML files are valid XML if you split them at the XML declaration and process each publication separately. I would expect trying to process them all at once to use a very large amount of memory.  Either way, the replacements you are doing aren't needed.

My solution was to create a class that owns the zipfile (for others that might not know, the data is a zip file containing one file that contains the concatenated XML files) and has a function that yields each XML file in turn.  I then use `ET.XML()` to process these files.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. I just started the split and was able to properly extract one XML file out of the list. I would repeat it for the rest. However, I still had to drop the line: '<!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>' as this was giving invalid token error.

Comment: That's very odd.  DOCTYPE  is valid in XML files, and there's nothing wrong with the one you are removing.  At least you have something that works.