# Parsing uspto xml files

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am trying to parse patent xml files of uspto to csv. I read and tried various methods. Lately, I came across with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324194/parsing-the-uspto-bulk-xml-files-using-python)
However, I could not find my way to the solution
You can find the xml file that I am trying to parse [here](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/patent/grant/redbook/bibliographic/2019/)
I also tried to use beautifulsoup, but no luck.

Here is the code that I use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as x


path = r"C:\Users\XX\Downloads\ipg190423\ipg190423.xml"
d = []
s = ""
f = open(path)
for l in f:
    if l == "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n":
        if len(s)>0:
            d.append(s)
        s = ""
    s += l
d.append(s)

index = 0
for xm in d:
    root = x.fromstring(xm)
    for e in root.iter(tag="patent-"):
        print(e)
        index += 1
        filename = format(str(index) + ".xml")
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(x.tostring(e))
```

Comment: You should show an example of the xml and what you are trying to parse from it.

Comment: The file is indeed too large, that's why I shared the link, so any zipped file in the link is fine, I try to parse the all of the information

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain in detail, **where** you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded one of those documents, and the problem is they are not valid XML documents. They consist of multiple XML documents concatenated together.  The basic structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant>
.
.
.
</us-patent-grant>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant>
.
.
.
</us-patent-grant>
```

For example, in `ipgb20190101_wk01.zip` there are 7162 XML documents concatenated together. Before you can parse this data you're going to have to write code to extract each XML document in sequence.

**Update**

You can extract the XML documents into separate files using the [`csplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html) command:

```
csplit -f 'patent-' -b '%02d.xml' ipgb20190101.xml '/^<?xml /' '{*}'
```

This will give you files `patent-0000.xml` through `patent-7126.xml` (assuming you use the same example data I did).

Comment: Hello thank you very much, should I use Python for this?

Comment: You could! You would just need to read through the file looking for the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` lines that mark the beginning of a new document. What you probably want to do is work on implementing a solution and post a new question if you run into specific technical issues.